# Node.js application is not working ARM Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, arm, nodejs

I use a Samsung ARM Chromebook as a dev machine, and as a result `Node.js` is absolutely essential.
 
In the past I've had no issues with it whatsoever. However, due to unfortunate circumstances I was recently forced to wipe my computer and start fresh. 
When I followed the same installation steps for Node.js as I always have (add the chris-lea ppa for the latest version), I didn't encounter any errors. However, when I type in node and nodejs, Node does not start. Nothing executes. Oddly, `node --version` returns what it should, v0.10.25.

- Is this an issue with the latest build of Node?
- How can I install an older one if that's the case?

Answer (score 3):

Using guide http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2013/08/nodejs-on-android.html I've compiled and installed NodeJS 0.10.35 on my Galaxy Note 8 (rooted, custom FlexBurst 1.2 ROM for SELinux disabling).

It was printing version but on any code execution it just replied my input and was doing nothing. After many trial and error, I’ve found a solution – trying guide here http://www.ibaivalencia.com/instalar-y-ejecutar-node-js-en-una-maquina-arm-con-linux/, I’ve compiled and installed node 0.11.9 and it was able to execute test code with console logging.

Here's a list of commands just in case if link is not working:

```sh
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.9/node-v0.11.9.tar.gz
tar -zxvf node-v0.11.9.tar.gz
cd node-v0.11.9
./configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanx, added code here, links are unreliable thing.

Comment: I no longer have a system on which to test this. If someone can confirm it works, I'll accept it.